# htaccess and php directory error

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling, directory

I am trying to access a php file located under a directory without the .php extension.

http://mydomain/Test/Products/Models

I am getting this error:

```
**Not Found**
**The requested URL /Test/Products/Models was not found on this server.**
```

If I use this, it works fine:

http://mydomain/Test/Products/Models.php

My htaccess files contains this php handler part:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
 </IfModule>
```

What do I need to change in my htaccess code so I can access files located in a directory without the .php extension

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: Regex is case sensitive, `a-z` will not match `Models`.  Look at the link suggested by @BenM, it has a nice answer you can use.